# jQuery Validate seems to pass invalid form to submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jQuery Validate to prevent my ajax form submit when three fields contain any characters other than digits.  Apparently I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what.

**EDIT**: There seem to be two errors. My validation rules use the field ID instead of the field name.  However, after fixing that problem, the form still validates unexpectedly..

This is my jQuery code:

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    formSubmits();

    /**
     * Handles all the form submits that go on.
     * This is primarily the ID search and the form submit.
     */
    function formSubmits() {

      /*** SAVE RECIPE ***/
      // validate form
      $("#category-editor").validate({
        rules: {
          "time-prep": {number: true},    /* not sure why validation doesn't work.. */
          "time-total": {number: true},   /* according to this, it should: http://goo.gl/9z2odC */
          "quantity-servings": {number: true}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

          // submit changes
          $.getJSON("setRecipe.php", $(form).serialize() )
            .done(function(data) {

              // de-empahaize submit button
              $('.footer input[type=submit]')
                .removeClass('btn-primary')
                .addClass('btn-default');
            });

          // prevent http submit
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Here's what I see in the inspector when I put a breakpoint inside the submitHandler.  It is getting to the submitHandler despite bad input (a value of 'dsdfd' instead of '123')

[image]

This is the relevant markup:

```
<form id="category-editor" class="form-inline" method="get">

....
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <div>
                    <label for="time-prep">Prep time (min):</label>
                    <input value="" id="time-prep" name="activeTime" class="form-control min-calc jqValidateNum" data-calc-dest="time-prep-desc" type="number"> 
                    <input value="" id="time-prep-desc" name="activeTimeDesc" class="form-control subtle" type="text"> 
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>                    
                  <div>
                    <label for="time-total">Total time (min):</label>
                    <input value="" id="time-total" name="totalTime" class="form-control min-calc jqValidateNum" data-calc-dest="time-total-desc" type="number"> 
                    <input value="" id="time-total-desc" name="totalTimeDesc" class="form-control subtle" type="text"> 
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>                    
                  <div>
                    <label for="quantity-servings">Servings:</label>
                    <input value="" id="quantity-servings" name="servings" class="form-control jqValidateNum" type="number"> 
                  </div>
                </div>

....
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you edit your OP with the code from the answer below?  Now the correct answer by Pointy makes no sense and the code in your question should be working.

Comment: Where is the rest of the markup for the form?  Where are the `form` tags?

Comment: Easy sparky.  Give me a moment between comments/edits before you downvote things - this is still a relevant question.

Comment: Easy there doublejack… please tell me where it says that I down-voted you?

Comment: Sorry, must have been a passer-by.  I guess that's why there's that cliche about ass-umptions.

Comment: You should not be editing the question in such a way to invalidate perfectly good answers… it's confusing to future readers.   Pointy fixed the most obvious broken part of your code so your question should continue to reflect that.

Comment: That's fair.  I'm not sure what protocol is when there is more than one problem/answer to a post.  I'll roll back my edit shortly.

Comment: _If_ the code contains several problems, then simply ask for follow-up as an addendum or in a comment.  This keeps everything intact and the answers make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your rules set up with the "id" values for the `<input>` elements instead of their "name" values. Should be:

```
    rules: {
      "activeTime": {number: true}, 
      "totalTime": {number: true},
      "servings": {number: true}
    },
```

*edit* — now that you've fixed that, I think the problem is that the "value" properties of the input elements are empty, because you've declared them `type=number`. Firefox and Chrome let you type anything into the fields, but they won't have a non-empty value unless the fields really do contain numbers.

If you also mark the fields as required, then it works. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48vwp/1/)

Comment: This is the correct answer (based on the original question), but the OP has since edited his code so this answer no longer makes any sense.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately it looks like this isn't my only problem - my code still does not work. I've corrected my post to reflect the current issue.

Comment: So you still see it passing validation in the debugger when you step through the code, and you're sure that the code in the browser is definitely updated to reflect the field names?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked it a number of times since your post.

Comment: Pointy beat me to it.  Yes, change them to `type="text"` and validation works.  http://jsfiddle.net/wfsT6/ ~ or make them `required`.

Comment: I see. Hm, I was hoping to allow empty submissions but prevent users from using text.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @doub1ejack, it's not good enough that the validation will prevent them from submitting text?

Comment: @doub1ejack if you make the fields plain text inputs then the values will be non empty if the user has typed/pasted anything into the fields.

Comment: I'll have to work this out.  I wanted the fields to be number types so that mobile devices would bring up the keypad.  And I want users to be able to submit a partial form and return to it later.  However, I don't want users to be submitting invalid data.  Perhaps this requires a custom validator?  I believe I can do that w/ jQuery Validate, right?

Comment: @doub1ejack well the root problem is that desktop browsers have really dumb behavior with `type=number` inputs. You can write a custom validator, but it'll also encounter the same brick wall: your code won't be able to tell the difference between a *truly* empty input and an input with an invalid number in it.

Comment: @doub1ejack I solve the problem in my own sites by generating (client-side) different code for touch and non-touch browsers.

Comment: Ok, thanks Pointy. So it sounds like there is no way to satisfy these three requirements for Chrome & Firefox then.  I assume it is not possible to specify the keypad type for a given field (then I could use a text field, validate for numeric content, and force a numeric keyboard to display on mobile devices)?  Seems unlikely.

Comment: @doub1ejack yes I feel your pain - that's why my templates just check (via Modernizr) for touch support (totally not a perfect solution).